# Reset back to google chrome default user

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I never had google users setup on my computer although I had all my bookmarks saved.

I thought by logging into my google account, it would save all my bookmarks and merge it to my account but I was wrong.  Instead it loaded blank bookmarks and I lost my original bookmarks that were on my computer.

I tried logging out of chrome user, but my bookmarks did not return.  Does anyone know how to get it back?

Also, I have a mac.

Comment: try this location for bookmarks file C:\Users\"User_name"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks.bak  If the file is not present, try deleted recovery.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have a mac

Comment: I think this might help you. http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-apps-games/309551-recover-bookmarks-chrome.html